# Google cloud storage access issue

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am a Google cloud project owner but I am not able to access the files in my project buckets.  I am getting the error

```
You need the storage.objects.list permission to list objects in this bucket. Ask a project or bucket owner to give you this permission and try again.
```

I am unable to copy files from the bucket as well and get an error `The caller does not have permission`

I have verified I'm authenticated as the right user (`gcloud auth list`).

What is going on here?

Comment: This is a recent error and it did not occur the last time I opened my bucket.

Comment: I see the latter.

Comment: With some research, I now know that this is called project-private "canned" ACL, the default permission setting. But I would still like to know what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I had lost the Storage Object permission to my bucket. The option to modify permissions wasn't visible to me as well. I had to ask anothe project owner to add storage object admin permission for me on that bucket and it fixed the problem.